# How to check if table contains column in JPA - Criteria API?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I joined two tables and get different columns from both tables to load them into dataTable. I want to order the columns by using dataTable but how can I understand which columns belogns to which tables? I mean, when I click order button on a **last_name column** from datatable, how can I write `order by table1_.last_name desc` because there are columns from table2 though.

So my code looks like this;

```
public Page<UserDTO> findByCriteria(String columnName, final String filters, String sort, Pageable pageable) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UserDTO> cq = cb.createQuery(UserDTO.class);
    Root<UserDTO> iRoot = cq.from(UserDTO.class);
    Join<UserDTO, User> bJoin= iRoot.join("user");



    cq.multiselect(bJoin.get("id"), bJoin.get("login"), bJoin.get("firstName"), bJoin.get("lastName"), bJoin.get("dayOfBirth"), iRoot.get("district"));


........

    if (!columnName.equals("district")) {
        .....
    }

.......

    if (sort.split(":")[0].equals("district") || columnName.equals("district")) {

        .......

    }

.........
}
```

As you see, I've used `!columnName.equals("district")` to distinguish tables from each other but this is not a generic way. I cannot use this method for another tables because they may use different columns so I'll have to change the columnName to differentitate tables again and again.

What I'm asking is that, is there a method like `contains` for **iRoot** and **bJoin** to check if **table contains** that **columnName** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using **try catch**:

```
        try {
            bJoin.<String>get(sort.split(":")[0]).as(String.class);

            //Use bJoin table to order
        }catch(Exception e) {
            //Use iRoot table to order
        }
```

By implementing **try catch**, I aimed to make a generic way to distinguish tables from each other.

Answer (score 1):

In Criteria API you should think in terms of entities and their properties, not in terms of tables and columns.

So, assuming you want to order on (for instance) `UserDTO.lastName`, this will be probably something along the lines:

```
cq.orderBy(iRoot.get("lastName"));
```

> What I'm asking is that, is there a method like contains for iRoot and bJoin to check if table contains that columnName ?

`Root` has a method `getModel` which returns an `EntityType` which provides metadata on the entity. You can check for attributes etc. there. Not exactly column names, but close.

Comment: Could you please show me a little example using sub methods of getModel?

Comment: @BurakN. Please ask this as another question. Maybe someone would be able to help.